# SSAS - Cube Browser - SQL Server 2012 RTM

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas-2012

Just playing around with SQL Server 2012 and tried to browse cube;  cannot see option of Drop Row Fields here / Drop column Fields here or Drop Filter Fields here.  Is this bug or is there any other setting to change the view.

Comment: As per MDSN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143682.aspx ) Analysis Services, Multidimensional Mode Cube browser in Management Studio and Cube Designer has been removed The cube browser control that let you drag and drop fields onto a PivotTable structure in Management Studio or in Cube Designer has been removed from the product. The control was an Office Web Control (OWC) component. OWC was deprecated by Office and is no longer available. :-(

Answer (score 4):

If they decided to take it the OWC-based browser, the least they could've done was to give us something that had better -- not worse -- functionality. What a major pain to click the Excel button every time you need to verify the cube data while developing...

Comment: I'm a fan of the Excel button.  I (like most developers) have dual monitors, so it's nice to be able to put excel up on one side and have my SSDT-solution on the other.

Comment: OWC was awesome and I miss it--not just in SSAS either. There was so much functionality you could do with it. It was built into many different products. I even used it for interactive web charts and graphs and pulling data from SQL Server. It's ironic that when Microsoft said OWC was no longer supported, that you could still finding it built into their currently supported products.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you don't have that functionality anymore but on the other hand, you can drag and drop your fields and by clicking on the "design button" you can have the generated MDX, which was not possible on 2008.

I think its a fair trade :)